# How to colorize console background with COLOREF RGB code?

Tags: c++, console

Here I ask you : How are we supposed to colorize the console background with only the `COLOREF` datatype as a parameter?

The most common way of colorizing background is by using `windows header` function `system("color --")`

However, this way is not possible, and I am tasked to find out if we can colorize the console background using only the `COLOREF` datatype.

I did some research, and what I came across was `SetConsoleAttribute()`, and the `windows header` function  `system("color --")`.

This is what I expect my code to be:

```cpp
COLOREF data = RGB(255, 0, 0);//red, basically

SetConsoleBackground(HDC *console, data);
```

Any way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `system("color --")` is **completely** unrelated to the Windows API. Now it seems that you want to use the *"Windows API"* (which actually isn't the Windows API), and at the same try attempt to avoid using the Windows API (without even realizing that you **are** referring to the Windows API). Things are completely opaque as to what you are trying to do, and what requirements you have. Voting to close.

Comment: @makhan must've understood that, as `system()` is a part of the `windows` header, he must've assumed that it is part of Windows API, or moreover, related to it. @makhan, edit your question and remove the relation of `system()` and `WINAPI`

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood relation between `WINAPI` and `system()`, I'll edit my question.

Comment: @ine `system` isn't declared in **any** of the Windows SDK header files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[NEW ANSWER (edit)]
So @IInspectable pointed out the the console now supports 24-bit full rgb colors so i did some research and managed to make it work.
This is how i solved it:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
struct Color
{
    int r;
    int g;
    int b;
};

void SetBackgroundColor(const Color& aColor)
{
    std::string modifier = "\x1b[48;2;" + std::to_string(aColor.r) + ";" + std::to_string(aColor.g) + ";" + std::to_string(aColor.b) + "m";
    printf(modifier.c_str());
}

void SetForegroundColor(const Color& aColor)
{
    std::string modifier = "\x1b[38;2;" + std::to_string(aColor.r) + ";" + std::to_string(aColor.g) + ";" + std::to_string(aColor.b) + "m";
    printf(modifier.c_str());
}
int main()
{
    // Set output mode to handle virtual terminal sequences
    HANDLE hOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    DWORD dwMode = 0;
    GetConsoleMode(hOut, &dwMode);

    dwMode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;
    SetConsoleMode(hOut, dwMode);

    SetForegroundColor({ 100,100,20 });
    SetBackgroundColor({ 50,100,10 });
    printf("Hello World\n");

    system("pause");
}
```

[OLD ANSWER]
The console only supports 256 different color combinations defined with a WORD which is 8 bits long. The background color is stored in the 4 higher bits. This means the console only has support for 16 different colors:

```
enum class Color : int
{
    Black = 0,
    DarkBlue = 1,
    DarkGreen = 2,
    DarkCyan = 3,
    DarkRed = 4,
    DarkPurple = 5,
    DarkYellow = 6,
    DarkWhite = 7,
    Gray = 8,
    Blue = 9,
    Green = 10,
    Cyan = 11,
    Red = 12,
    Purple = 13,
    Yellow = 14,
    White = 15,
};
```

To set the background color of the typed characters, you could do:

```
void SetWriteColor(const Color& aColor)
{
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(hConsole, static_cast<WORD>(aColor) << 4);
}
```

Comment: Best Answer so far. +rep

Comment: But what about the background color of the console itself, not the text?

Comment: The "<< 4" shifts the bits 4 steps to the left; 00001010 becomes 1010000 putting the color in the background bits, if you want to change both the text color and the background color you could use an or-operator "|": WORD color = (backgroundColor <<4) | foregroundColor

Comment: This answer was correct, a decade ago. Today, Windows' console [supports 24-bit colors](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/24-bit-color-in-the-windows-console/). Sure, this is the *"best answer so far"*. It's also the worst answer so far.

Comment: You can say that again. heh

Comment: I would love to know how to implement this in c++ if you would care to take the time to explain how. I have as of yet not found a way to implement more than 8-bit colors.

Comment: Can I know why you have added `Color` as a pointer type?

Comment: My thinking was that I did not want to send a copy of the object.

Comment: @IInspectable Thank you for pointing out my mistake. I updated the answer to match

Comment: @Cooltomten, I've tried the code you provided, it just seems to print a string. not change the background